# How does Christopher Moltisanti respond to the "bridge and tunnel boy" insult?

Tags: dialogue, the-sopranos

During the scene where Chris meets the movie chick, he says something to some unruly brokers that club.  Initially, the broker gets snotty with Chris, calling him a "bridge and tunnel boy", but Chris says something to him that scares the crap out of him.

[The link is here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rP9ThXl1hX4)

I am pretty sure we can only speculate what is said, but any ideas?

Comment: He could have said a well written and detailed threat, and one of the video comments suggests that he could have grabbed the guys hand and made him feel he wears a gun.

Answer (score 1):

He responds by discreetly threatening the unruly broker. It can be safely assumed that he whispered a very credible threat. The above comment about Christopher "grabbing the guy's hand and making him feel his gun" sounds quite plausible.